# Why PropertyChanged could be null when gets binded?

Tags: c#, wpf

here is the problem i am encountering, i will use the class names in my demo to describe my problem:

i have to show something on a datagrid, as a view of `Item`. but the `Item` itself is a wrapper class of the real data source, `Dummy`.

`Container` is the manager of all `Dummy`'s, it will call `Poll` periodically(in my demo, 1s) and it internally queries the remote server to decide the current value(in demo, i simply flip the boolean). and after that, `Container` will go through all `Item`'s and `Notify` them changes may be made.

but my problem is, the if branch in `Notify` called by `Container` won't get in, since `PropertyChanged` is null! but if i change it in the `DataGrid`, i.e. `dg`, by double click, this event gets subscribed. so my problem is, how can i successfully notify in `Container`? is there any a way to make `DataGrid` subscribe to `PropertyChanged` all the time?

btw, if i use a debugger to get in, they are null too.

Following is my demo code:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg"  Margin="0,0,0,35"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,0,10,10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c# part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Container _container;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _container = new Container();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dg.ItemsSource = _container.GetItems();
        }
    }

    public class Dummy
    {
        public Dummy()
        {
            _done=false;
        }
        private bool _done;
        public bool Done {
            get { return _done; }
            // set will trigger something remotely too.
            set { _done = value; }
        }

        public void Poll() { _done=!_done;}
    }

    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Dummy dummy;
        public Item(Dummy dum)
        {
            dummy = dum;
        }
        public bool Done
        {
            get { return dummy.Done; }
            set
            {
                dummy.Done = value;
                Notify();
            }
        }

        public void Notify()
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Done"));
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        private List<Dummy> dummies;
        private DispatcherTimer _updateTimer;
        public Container()
        {
            dummies = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                       select new Dummy()).ToList();
        }

        private IEnumerable<Item> items;
        public Item[] GetItems()
        {
            if (_updateTimer != null)
                _updateTimer.Stop();
            items=dummies.Select(x => new Item(x));
            _updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _updateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            _updateTimer.Tick += (_1, _2) =>
            {
                foreach (var item in dummies)
                {
                    item.Poll();
                }
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    item.Notify();
                }
            };
            _updateTimer.Start();
            return items.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing List<Dummy> in container to ObservableCollection<Dummy>

Comment: @reggaeguitar you mean Dummy or Item? why Dummy? it's internal.

Comment: @reggaeguitar i can't display Dummy directly, since Dummy in my real project is third party, so i need to have a wrapper.

Comment: the first line in the Container class, change the type of dummies from List<Dummy> to ObservableCollection<Dummy>

Comment: @reggaeguitar not working. `private ObservableCollection<Dummy> dummies;
        private DispatcherTimer _updateTimer;
        public Container()
        {
            dummies = new ObservableCollection<Dummy>(from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                                      select new Dummy());
        }`

Comment: look at the Output tab when you first start the app and look for any binding errors, that's the only other advice I can offer